# Mmma connectivity . parquet. python

Tags: export, import, output-formatting, output

Is there any way to exchange data in binary format with python ?
Example. 
a) I have data in Mmma and want to export them to make use in python ...

b) Want to use Parquet format

Comment: Why not use an intermediate format that both Mathematica and Python can easily read, and then export to whatever format you want from Python?

Comment: @C.E. speed and efficiency prevent such a solution proposal. Mmma hasn't been the kindest to the latest developments that data scientist need to use.

Comment: You should have a look at WXF. The [Wolfram Client for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) library implements data transfer between python and Mathematica using WXF. The documentation contains examples.

Comment: tl,rd this is py --> M , what about M --> py ? I asked for how m data/output can be exchanged in binary format w/ python ... what are u suggesting ? Please explain, rather than pointing fingers.